# Is jQuery Elastic SlideShow compatible with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Elastic Image Slide Show in Twitter Bootstrap from the following:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/21/elastic-image-slideshow-with-thumbnail-preview/

It is showing extra margin on right side for main images and the images got shrunk in smaller screens. But if i disable the script, the image looks perfect and does not get shrink in mobile view (only 1 image is visible) But the Plugin doesn't work at all.......

So it means that this plugin does not work with bootstrap??

or anyone has any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to override the bootstrap img properties with this code

```
.ei-slider img{
    max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Of course it works, the thing is in the css itself probably there are css properties overlapping each other and causing it to break. now it will be a hard but instructive work to find what it can be.

Good luck on that!